# display popup box after click of a button and before redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There is a button that is supposed to redirect to another page, but before its redirection and after the click i wish to display a popup box that may contain any message
Here is my button

```
<a href="addorder.php?id=<? echo $row01['id']; ?>" ><button id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Request</button></a>
```

i tried using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    alert();/whatever the message may be
        location.href = "www.google.com";
    };
```

But it didn't work, can anyone tel how i can achieve this

Comment: what is not working??are you able to show popup or able to redirect to any page without popup?what error you get.post error details.

Answer (score 1):

Here example to achieve that:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');
  location.href = "http://google.com";

});

// or 
/*$('#myButton').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');
  location.href="http://google.com";  
});*/

// if wanna add confirm box use this
/*$('#myButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
    location.href = "http://google.com";
  } else {
    return;
  }
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="addorder.php?">
  <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Request</button>
</a>
```

p/s: added functionality for confirm box(just give an option to choose)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(myButton).onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
   alert("foo");
location.href= "www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: you need to describe how its different to the code user has already tried and stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
    location.href = "www.google.com";
};
```

```html
  <button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jquery function as below!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
    alert("Write your message here");
    location.href= "www.google.com"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  confirm window (ie. Yes/No options).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    if (window.confirm('Do you really go to another page?'))
    {
       location.href = "www.google.com";
    }
    else
    {

    }

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, Try using prompt()...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        prompt("A Message");
        location.href = "www.google.com";
    };
</script>
```